# Unsigned shift operation yields different results for same number of shift

Tags: java, operators, bit-shift, unsigned, shift

Why does it yield two different results if in both cases we are performing 32 bits unsigned right shift?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = -1;
        i = i>>>31;
        i = i>>>1;
        
        int j = -1;
        j = j>>>32;
        
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
0
-1
```

Comment: before shifting, the shift is taken `% 32` (see [JLS, §15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)). So `j>>>32` is equivalent to `j>>>0`